# Google API working on Browser and not in Windows 8 app

Tags: javascript, google-maps, windows-8, google-api

I am trying the following code to get the Location of the user. It works on browsers but on Windows 8 App compilation, it says,

> Java runtime error, 'Google' is undefined!

I was suggested to load Maps Api. How do I do that? Proper Code and answer please. On satisfaction, I will vote you certainly.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Get Location</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
</head>

<body>

<p id="locResults">Click the button to get your coordinates:</p>
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
<script>
function getLocation(){
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
  else{document.getElementById("locResults").innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {
  document.getElementById("locResults").innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  
  document.getElementById("locResults").innerHTML="Getting Your Location...";  
  getReverseGeocodingData(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
  }
function getReverseGeocodingData(lat, lng) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    // This is making the Geocode request
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
        if (status !== google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            document.getElementById("locResults").innerHTML = status;
        }
        // This is checking to see if the Geoeode Status is OK before proceeding
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            console.log(results);
            var address = (results[0].formatted_address);
            document.getElementById("locResults").innerHTML = address;
        }
    });
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to call the Google Maps:

```
 function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(16.4706001, -33.6728973),
          zoom:3,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it is still displaying the same error message, google is undefined. Any more tips?

Comment: Well if in your code you don't have the API key, but that makes some sense. The other thing is that you need to check the order and let the browser know what is 'google' before you use other objects of their API's. Just that.